# Basics about process statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In test bench in xilinx, I recognized that a statement like

```
 clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;
```

According to my knowledge, process is implemented when the argument is changed. However, in here, we do not declare any argument. Why does this code works? In what conditions? And, why do we have to use tag like "clk_process:" or in port mapping. I am sorry this is a very basic question:( Even brief explanation suffices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.2 Wait statement:

> The wait statement causes the suspension of a process statement or a procedure.

11.3 Process statement:

> A process statement defines an independent sequential process representing the behavior of some portion of the design.

Para 12:

> The execution of a process statement consists of the repetitive execution of its sequence of statements. After the last statement in the sequence of statements of a process statement is executed, execution will immediately continue with the first statement in the sequence of statements.

Back to 10.2, para 8:

> The execution of a wait statement causes the time expression to be evaluated to determine the timeout interval. It also causes the execution of the corresponding process statement to be suspended, where the corresponding process statement is the one that either contains the wait statement or is the parent (see 4.3) of the procedure that contains the wait statement. The suspended process will resume, at the latest, immediately after the timeout interval has expired.

And back to 11.3, para 4:

> If a process sensitivity list appears following the reserved word **process**, then the process statement is assumed to contain an implicit wait statement as the last statement of the process statement part; this implicit wait statement is of the form
>
> **wait** on sensitivity_list ;

(Which covers the case of a process sensitivity list).

What you refer to as a tag is a label.  Labels are optional by and large (particularly here although there are places where labels can be required).

The last paragraph of 10.1 (10. Sequential statements):

> All sequential statements may be labeled. Such labels are implicitly declared at the beginning of the declarative part of the innermost enclosing process statement or subprogram body.

The last paragraph of 11.1 (11. Concurrent statements):

> All concurrent statements may be labeled. Such labels are implicitly declared at the beginning of the declarative part of the innermost enclosing entity declaration, architecture body, block statement, or generate statement.

(And a process statement is a concurrent statement, see 11.1 paragraph 2).

11.3, paragraph 2:

```
process_statement ::= 
    [ process_label : ]
        [ postponed ] process [ ( process_sensitivity_list ) ] [ is ] 
              process_declarative_part
        begin
            process_statement_part
        end [ postponed ] process [ process_label ] ;
```

Where the square brackets enclose an optional item. (See 1.3.2 Syntactic description).

Answer (score 1):

A process like this is often used in testbench. The process is used to generate a clock, that should be used in the tested design.
You only need to define a "clk_period" like 1us and get a 1MHz clock named "clk".

Very Important this code is not synthesizeable it is only for simulation!

The "Tag" "clk_process" is only the process name, you could call it how ever you want.